# Is this undefined behaviour (String modification)

Tags: c, compiler-errors

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void modify(char **s){
  char *new_name = "Australia";
  *s = new_name;
}

int main(){
  char *name = "New Holland";
  modify(&name);
  printf("%s\n", name);
  return 0;
}
```

Here we are trying to modify string literal `name` of `char*` type which is stored in a read-only location. So does this fall into undefined behavior?

Comment: @CherryDT it is not UB. String literals have static storage duration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First of all, you do not modify the string; you assign to the pointers, and pointers are not strings! They can only reference the C strings (which are nul-terminated arrays of `char`).
2. It's my understanding of the C standard (6.5.2.5 - especially examples, quoted below) that string literals have a `static` storage duration, and it is not UB as you assign the reference to the string literal (not the local variable). It does not matter where string literals are physically stored.

> EXAMPLE 5 The following three expressions have different meanings:
>
> ```
> "/tmp/fileXXXXXX" 
> (char []){"/tmp/fileXXXXXX"} 
> (const char> []){"/tmp/fileXXXXXX"}
> ```
>
> **The first always has static storage
> duration** and has type array of char, but need not be modifiable; the
> last two have automatic storage duration when they occur within the
> body of a function, and the first of these two is modifiable.

Comment: Yep almost understood, just a clarification ; ```it is not UB as you assign the reference to string literal (not the local variable)```, so by this you mean, if I have assigned (inside the function) ```*s = var (of char[] type)``` then that would be UB right? (because it's a local variable and dies after the function completion)

Comment: if `var` has automatic storage duration then it will be an UB. Otherwise no UB